# How do I load an array from values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, sudzc

I'm sorry in advance for a newbie question. I've been working on this for days, and I'm having comprehension problems. I used sudzc to help connect to my web service. The example function only returns 1 result (the last one). How can I load all the results into an array so that I can find CSHR_NUM = 8?  I'm not sure if there is a problem with: 
    - (void) GetCashiersHandler: (id) value

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The sudzc logging returns (there are hundreds of entries, I cut it down):

```
<TC diffgr:id="TC1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
 <CSHR_POS_NAME>JACKSON<CSHR_POS_NAME />
  <CSHR_NUM>8</CSHR_NUM>
</TC>
<TC diffgr:id="TC2" msdata:rowOrder="1"> 
 <CSHR_POS_NAME>ALISON</CSHR_POS_NAME> 
  <CSHR_NUM>464</CSHR_NUM>
</TC>
```

I use the example method of calling:

[service GetCashiers:self action:@selector(GetCashiersHandler];

```
// Handle the response from GetCashiers to get login in name.
- (void) GetCashiersHandler: (id) value
  {
// Do something with the CXMLNode* result
 CXMLNode *result = (CXMLNode*)value;

 NSLog(@"I returned the value: %@", result);

  }
```

NSLog Results:

```
I returned the value: {
 GetCashiersResult = {
diffgram = {
NewDataSet = {
TC = {
  "CSHR_NUM" = 464;
    "CSHR_POS_NAME" = ALLISON;
      };
   };
};
schema = {
  element = {
    complexType = {
   choice = {
  element = {
    complexType = {
  sequence = {
  element = 0;
        };
      };
    };
   };
   };
  };
 };
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray * myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

// loop over items to add and add them with

[myData addObject:myItem];
```

Comment: it returns the same results 5 times in the NSLog

Comment: Are you calling alloc/initwithcapacity just once, and add object five times?

Comment: I think it's a sudzc problem.  it loops through the deserialize overwriting the previous node.